# Java event is killed when a function for audio playing is called

Tags: java, events, audio

I am facing a strange programming problem. It has exhausted me but with no solution found!

My program is mainly dependent on an event (Java Listener) that is fired from an external hardware for receiving an audio message from that hardware.Inside the eventHandler i do the following

1. pass the received message to a static method "decode" from another class  which returns data
2. then I open FileOutputStream, write these data "audio" to a file,and close the FileOutputStream.
3. I call a static method "play" from another class to play the audio file.

The problem is: whenever the method "Play" is called for the first time, it executes correctly but it causes the event to stop raising and the program to terminate but without exceptions. When I comment out the play method, everything becomes okay!

Do you have some idea about a method causing program termination ?

```
 public void messageReceived(int to,Message message)
 {

speexAudioMsg msg = (speexAudioMsg)message;
 try{

    byte[] output = jspeexDecoder.decode(msg.get_frame());

os = new FileOutputStream(file);
os.write(output);
os.close();
Player.play();  
  }
  catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the event thread to play the music. Try calling Player.play() in a new thread.

new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() {Player.play()}}).start();

here is an example:

```
    static String url = "http://www.stackoverload.com";

    public static void threadTest() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    URL url2 = new URL(url);
                    url2.openStream();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }).run();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried the line and got this error:<identifier> expected
new Thread(new Runnable() { Player.play();}).start(); and the error arrow point to play() . do you have an idea?

Comment: I have updated with an example and fixed the original code snippet